# SNMPv2 to v3 conversion

Tags: ipv4, snmp, snmpv3

Can I use a Cisco router to convert SNMPv2 from an end device in one network to SNMPv3 and the C&M software in another network?

The end device can only handle SNMPv2, but the C&M community is setup as SNMPv3.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Protocols above layer 4 are off limits here, however SNMPv2 and SNMPv3 are completely different with how authentication works and also that SNMPv3 can be encrypted.  I don’t see how you would be able to convert from one to the other since they work entirely different than one another.

SNMPv2 uses community strings, while SNMPv3 uses username/password and may or may not use encryption.

Comment: Proxy. I'm not aware of one for SNMP. (i.e. you talk to the proxy as v3 and it talks to the v2 device. in theory, this wouldn't be hard to do.) [ Edit: https://github.com/etingof/snmpfwd ]

Comment: @Ricky Never seen that before, but that’s not really converting anything and it’s adding another point of failure.  It would be easier to just change the configs and be done.

Comment: Also, it appears net-snmp has supported this since 5.0. 'tho I would bet OP's software doesn't support v3 contexts.

Comment: @Ricky Supported for what?  Forwarding SNMPv2 for one server to SNMPv3 on another?

Comment: "proxy" (see also: man snmp.conf(5))

Comment: @Ricky Cool. Unfortunately, SNMP and product recommendations are still off limits here, but if they want to go through that product’s man pages to learn it, have it.